# Remove rows with the same values by consecutive wave in R

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, data-manipulation

I have a panel data frame of friendship ties by wave. I want to delete the friendship ties that appear in consecutive waves and keep only friendship ties that are not consecutive.

By not consecutive friendship ties I mean if person A nominates person B as their friend in time 1 and time 3, but not time 2.

Sample of HAVE data:

```
id   friend   wave
1    4        1
1    5        1
1    2        2
1    5        3
1    2        3
2    1        1
2    4        1
2    1        2
2    1        3
4    3        1
4    5        2
4    3        3
5    1        1 
5    3        2
5    4        2
5    2        3
6    5        1
6    5        2
6    5        4
```

WANT data:

```
 id   friend   wave
 1    5        1
 1    5        3
 4    3        1
 4    3        3
 6    5        2
 6    5        4
```

Comment: Ah- you're right, fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Your definition is unclear.  If you have the data set `df <- tibble(id = c(6,6,6), friend = c(5,5,5), wave = c(1,2,4))` - do you want to keep the 2nd row?  It's consecutive with it's predecessor, but non-consecutive with its successor.

Comment: @DavidT in the case of that example I would want to keep row 2 and 4 since id =6 and friend = 5 did not appear in wave = 3.

Comment: Well, those data will be excluded by @RonakShaw 's `df %>% group_by(id, friend) %>% filter(n() > 1 && all(diff(wave) != 1))`.  I _think_ you're trying to select pairs of records where `id`, `friend` are the same, and there's a gap between the `wave`, even if both of the records are consecutive with some other record.  But looking at your example code, I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it, apologies since that wasn't clear from the example data.

Comment: OK, so I posted an alternative solution, below.

Comment: Updated to reflect the expected output David brought up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments, we're selecting pairs of records where `id, friend` are the same, and there's a gap between the wave, even if both of the records are consecutive with some other record.  Add a few records to your data:

```
df <- read_table("id   friend   wave
1    4        1
1    5        1
1    2        2
1    5        3
1    2        3
2    1        1
2    4        1
2    1        2
2    1        3
4    3        1
4    5        2
4    3        3
5    1        1 
5    3        2
5    4        2
5    2        3
6    5        1
6    5        2
6    5        4") %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

Add a `lead` and a `lag` column.

```
interm <- df %>% 
  group_by(id, friend) %>% 
    # wave has to be in ascending order for the 'lead' and 'lag
  arrange(id, friend, wave) %>% 
  mutate(next_wave = lead(wave, default = NA),
         prev_wave = lag(wave, default = NA),
           # Keep any that have a wave-difference > 1, ahead or behind.
           # This is the tricky part.
         keep = (next_wave - wave > 1) | 
           (wave - prev_wave > 1))
```

What do we have so far?

```
R > interm
# A tibble: 19 x 6
# Groups:   id, friend [12]
      id friend  wave next_wave prev_wave keep 
   <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl> <lgl>
 1     1      4     1        NA        NA NA   
 2     1      5     1         3        NA TRUE 
 3     2      1     1         2        NA NA   
 4     2      4     1        NA        NA NA   
 5     4      3     1         3        NA TRUE 
 6     5      1     1        NA        NA NA   
 7     6      5     1         2        NA NA   
 8     1      2     2         3        NA NA   
 9     2      1     2         3         1 FALSE
10     4      5     2        NA        NA NA   
11     5      3     2        NA        NA NA   
12     5      4     2        NA        NA NA   
13     6      5     2         4         1 TRUE 
14     1      5     3        NA         1 TRUE 
15     1      2     3        NA         2 NA   
16     2      1     3        NA         2 NA   
17     4      3     3        NA         1 TRUE 
18     5      2     3        NA        NA NA   
19     6      5     4        NA         2 TRUE
```

Looking right, even if a bit sloppy.  Let's clean up.

```
answer <- interm %>% 
  filter(keep) %>% 
  select(- next_wave, - prev_wave) %>%
  ungroup()

answer
# A tibble: 6 x 4
     id friend  wave keep 
  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>
1     1      5     1 TRUE 
2     1      5     3 TRUE 
3     4      3     1 TRUE 
4     4      3     3 TRUE 
5     6      5     2 TRUE 
6     6      5     4 TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

For each `id` and `friend` we can select groups that have more than 1 row and the difference between all of the `wave` values is not 1.

This can be done using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(id, friend) %>% filter(n() > 1 && all(diff(wave) != 1))

#     id friend  wave
#  <int>  <int> <int>
#1     1      5     1
#2     1      5     3
#3     4      3     1
#4     4      3     3
```

Base R :

```
subset(df, as.logical(ave(wave, id, friend, FUN = function(x)
                      length(x) > 1 && all(diff(x) != 1))))
```

and `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .SD[.N > 1 && all(diff(wave) != 1)], .(id, friend)]
```